# How do you convert a fileinput.input into integer in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve day 1 of 30 Days of Code by Hackerrank and tried converting the fileinput.input into integer.

I tried converting it into integer using `int()` and converting it to a string using `str()` then integer using `int()`. Both methods don't seem to work.

```
i = 4
d = 4.0
s = 'HackerRank '
# Declare second integer, double, and String variables.

# Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.

# Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.

# Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.

# Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
# The 's' variable above should be printed first.
import fileinput
i2 = fileinput.input()
d2 = fileinput.input()
s2 = str(fileinput.input())

i3 = i + i2
d3 = d2 * 2

print(str(i3))
print(str(d3))
print(str(s+s2))
```

I expected it to be:

```
16
8.0
HackerRank is the best place to learn and practice coding!
```

but it returned:

```py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Solution.py", line 20, in <module>
        i3 = i + i2
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'FileInput'
```

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to be using `fileinput.input`? If you're just trying to prompt the user to type something, that's conventionally done with only `input`, no `fileinput` module required.

Comment: `fileinput.input` returns a generator. If you want to pop the first element of a generator, use `next`. But as already said, you want `input`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need `input()` not `fileinput()`, the goal is just to convert user `input`:

As a hint, your `inputs` should look like this:

`num = int(input())` or `s = str(input())`

If you still are having trouble, there is a good [solution](https://github.com/xeoneux/30-Days-of-Code/blob/master/1%20-%20Data%20Types/Solution.py) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

import fileinput and the rest fileinputs are not needed. In python you can not mix two different variable types, thus `i2` needs to be an integer.

Instead, specify your variable i2,d2,s2 inputs as mentioned in comment "save an integer, double, and String to your variables". In python `float` is used instead `double` as it's used in other compiled programming languages.

Eg. `s2 = str(fileinput.input())` -> `s2 = str(input())` or `s2 = input()`as input() is already string by default.

Also take note of "# Print the **sum** of the double variables on a new line."